# Cannot convert type string[] to string when value is assigned with number in [] 

Tags: c#, arrays, string

Why does it complain about it not being able to convert a string array to a string when the values are strings within a string array

Code:

```
 int i;
            string[] Filenames;

            OpenFileDialog UnConvertedFilesList = new OpenFileDialog();
            if (UnConvertedFilesList.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {

                foreach (string FileName in UnConvertedFilesList.FileNames)
                {

                    //Right Here
                    Filenames[i] = Filenames;
                    AudioFiles_listbox.Items.Add(FileName);
                    i++;
                }

            }//if
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("File does not exist");
            }
```

edit:  that line to Changed Filenames[i] = FileName

Now it says "Use of unassigned local variable 'Filenames' and same thing for i

Their defined at the top of the function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have an extra "s" on your name there:

```
//Right Here
Filenames[i] = Filenames;
```

should be:

```
//Right Here
Filenames[i] = FileName;
```

More than that, though, your Filenames[] array is currently `null`. Once you fix your first problem you'll have that to contend with.  My recommendation there is to skip using the array entirely and just go directly to the AudioFiles_listbox.  And once you do that, you can go right for the Listbox's AddRange method:

```
AudioFiles_listbox.Items.AddRange(UnConvertedFilesList.FileNames);
```

Comment: It's actually FileName - note the capital N. But he should figure that out. Also i is never initialised. He needs int i=0. Cheers +1

Comment: @JoelCoehoom, please provide the solution code for doing this alternative approach you described.

Comment: Yeah for "string[] FileNames;" I get the error: "The variable 'FileNames is declared but never used" so if i leave off that line it will still work? I have a problem w/ the window loading twice and not allowing me to select more than one file.

Answer (score 0):

"Use of unassigned" means that you aren't using it anywhere within that method or segment of code...  your assignment is now OK, but it's not being used.

HTH.